# Trigger with update other table, from aggregation of another table

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm try to make a trigger on MySql.

Cenario:
i've 3 tables:

- com_proposals
- com_proposals_items
- com_proposals_subitems

IMPORTANT: the three tables has this columns (value_gross,value_disc_auto,value_disc_comercial)
And the source of this values is aways from the last one - com_proposals_subitems

If i updates qty in second table, i've to update the principal table (com_proposals)
And that needs the calculation(sum) of third table(..subitems).
Look:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_com_proposals_cart_items_updatevalues 
AFTER UPDATE ON com_proposals_cart_items
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    SET @id = OLD.id;
    SET @prop_id = OLD.proposal_id;
    
    SELECT
        @gross := sum(value_gross),
        @auto := sum(value_disc_auto),
        @com := sum(value_disc_comercial)
    from
        com_proposals_cart_subitems
    where
        cart_item_id = @id;
        
    OLD.value_gross = @gross;
    OLD.value_disc_auto = @auto;
    OLD.value_disc_comercial = @com;
    
    
    SELECT
        @item_gross := sum(value_gross),
        @item_auto := sum(value_disc_auto),
        @item_com := sum(value_disc_comercial)
    from
        com_proposals_cart_items
    where
        id = @id;
    
    UPDATE com_proposals set 
        value_gross = @item_gross,
        value_disc_auto = @item_autoy,
        value_disc_comercial = @item_com
    WHERE id = @prop_id;
END$$    

DELIMITER ;
```

But, i'm getting a syntax error:

```
Error occurred during SQL script execution

Razão:
 SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.value_gross = @gross;

    OLD.value_disc_auto = @auto;

    OLD.value_disc_comercial' at line 17
```

Someone kwons whats happining?? THANKS A LOT!!!
Server version: 5.7.30-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (Ubuntu)